# References: Lie derivations of Full matrix algebra

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, derivations

I want, if possible a list of references that trait Lie derivations of Full matrix algebras. Other than [Lie derivations of generalized matrix algebras](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437951200448X)
.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have stopped in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I just forget the word "and".